# Hover on scroll effect causes width of element to change

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a scrollbar appear only when a user hovers over the component. The problem is that the scrollable element has a cutoff on the side of it when it is hovered compared to when it is not, like in the video below

[image]

This is the css I am using to make the scrollbar appear when it is hovered over

```
.scroll-on-hover:hover {
    overflow-y: scroll !important;
}
```

And then it's applied like

```
<div style="position: fixed;" class="scroll-on-hover">
       <nav style="background-color: navy; height: 100%;" >
           ...
       </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please show us your Code? I mean the HTML and CSS

Comment: By default `overflow-y` is `auto`, and for most of the browsers it's equivalent to `scroll`, may be you are changing something more, please provide the style for that block of elements and the structure if you can.

Comment: @Leo I want to hide the scrollbar when the element isn't hovered, facebook is an example of a site that does this, when you scroll on the left menu

Comment: So, you did it well, I see your concern is the background behavior, the fact is that facebook doesn't use a "real" scroll, the scroll bar you see, is actually a div, and it's quite complex to achiev comparing with the current solution.

Comment: I encourage you to inpect that scroll bar from facebook with a dev tool, and see what happens. And maybe reverse engineer it.

Answer (score 1):

It happens because you are forcing it to show the scroll bar.

It is the expected behavior, **a scroll bar will always occupy and overlap the content**.

As you say:

> I am trying to make a scrollbar appear only when a user hovers over the component. ...

There are two problems:

1. By making it just scrollable or not, you are not showing or hidding the elements.
2. The `:hover` works only on desktops, mobile cannot do that.

For the first problem, I encourage you to use "play" with `display`, `translate`, or any other prop that actually can hide and show the elements.

For the second, a similar approach can be `:active`, it's when you click and touch on mobile, instead of `:hover` that works only for the desktop mouse.

---

**Edit**

What you are looking for, is not a native scroll bar, it is a `div`, actually a lot of them and a huge peace of functionality.

Facebook is making a mimic of a scroll bar, a custom one, and for sure it's way more complex than an `overflow-y` style.

Comment: How do you suggest I use `display` or `translate`?

Comment: @Sam, I added a bit more of info. to the answer, I hope it helps you.